# Youtube video api video not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

Hi guys im playing with the youtube video background api, and want to set a video in my page on the background of a div that i already set, so i have this html:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="video">

</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#video').YTPlayer({
        fitToBackground: true,
        videoId: 'LSmgKRx5pBo',
        playerVars: {
            modestbranding: 0,
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 1,
            showinfo: 0,
            branding: 0,
            rel: 0,
            autohide: 0,
            start: 10
        }
    });
})
```

this is the [link](https://github.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground) from where i am using the api, i don't get any console error, what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/mLwyyay9/4/) is a working fiddle with some text and a button above the video :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').YTPlayer({
    fitToBackground: true,
    videoId: 'LSmgKRx5pBo',
    playerVars: {
      modestbranding: 0,
      autoplay: 1,
      controls: 1,
      showinfo: 0,
      branding: 0,
      rel: 0,
      autohide: 0,
      start: 10
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#video {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.ytplayer-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground/dbdfa723/src/jquery.youtubebackground.js"></script>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="video">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <input type="submit" value="some button" />
</div>
```